# pass action-sql-expression to a topic subscription

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I want to do action-sql-expression command on a subscription. I have this:

```
az servicebus topic subscription rule create ^
--resource-group %resourcegroup_name% ^
--namespace %namespace_name% ^
--topic-name %topic_name% ^
--subscription-name %subscription_name% ^
--name %rule_name ^
--action-sql-expression SET TopicName=%topic_name%
```

But I am getting this error:

```
az: error: unrecognized arguments: TopicName=MyTopic
```

How can I pass the argument for action-sql-expression?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the sql statement in quotation marks. So use it like below

`--action-sql-expression "SET TopicName=%topic_name%"`

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-tutorial-topics-subscriptions-cli?view=azurermps-5.2.0).

Comment: did not help. I got this message this time:

BadRequest - Value cannot be null.                                                                                      Parameter name: sqlExpression CorrelationId:

Comment: As you see in my code, I dont use --filter-sql-expression at all. I dont know if I have to use this to could use --action-sql-expression. Because in the link you gave me, they used both of them in the same command.

Comment: No,  you dont need to add filter-sql-expression. They are optional parameters.

Comment: Exactly, but why I got BadRequest - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: sqlExpression CorrelationId: ... ?!